# Check if URL exist in file before crawling with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to use `Scrapy` to crawl a website's data. There's an element in every page content which is a URL.

As the website have too many pages, I want to **crawl only pages which contain a URL of specified in a TXT file** by me.

So crawler checks the website, **extracts the response elements**, **checks if extracted URL from the page's content exist in that file**, saves the response data into a JSON file.

Here is what I've so far :

```
import scrapy
import json
import uuid
import os
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class ItemSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "items"
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/template/template1.html']
    rules = (Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow = (), canonicalize=True, unique=True), callback = 'parse_obj', follow = True), )
    def parse_obj(self, response):
        for link in LxmlLinkExtractor(allow = self.allowed_domains, canonicalize=True, unique=True).extract_links(response):
            with open("urls.txt", "r") as checkfile:
                if response.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'example2.net')]/text()").extract() in checkfile.readlines():
                    response_obj = {}
                    counter = 1
                    for item in response.css("#dle-content"):
                        title = item.css(".storytitle::text").extract()
                        title_name = title[0]
                        response_obj[counter] = {
                        'demo': item.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'example2.net')]/text()").extract(),
                        'websiteurl': response.url,
                        'date': item.css(".copy > a:first-child::text").extract(),
                        }
                    counter += 1
                    filename = str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".json"
                    with open(os.path.join('C:/scrapy/tutorial/result/', filename), 'w') as fp:
                        json.dump(response_obj, fp)
```

**Second problem**:
It seems that the crawler doesn't stop crawling. The website doesn't have that many pages which this crawler save as results. It doesn't stop at all, more than 150K result files generated then I stopped command myself.

I think it's recrawling results. Am I right? 
I know that scrapy will not crawl already crawled urls.But I think maybe something is wrong here which prevents this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing the URLs you want to scrape in a database and passing them through as the start urls?

Comment: Did you get what I asked? The URLS for scraping is completely different from the URLS which I want to check if exist. For example, this is the url which I want to scrape : `example.com/blahblah` and this is the the url which is extracted from scraping and I want to check after scraping if it's available at the file (urls.txt) : `demo.com/anotherblahbalh`